# How to delete an object in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, apache-commons-dbutils

I use Dbutils to call elements in one table of database

```
private void showEvent(){

    try {
        String query="SELECT EventID, MemberID,Description, Date, 
        Time, Venue, EventTypes  FROM formal UNION SELECT EventID, 
        MemberID,Description, Date, Time, Venue, EventTypes FROM social";

        ps = c.prepareStatement(query);

        rs=ps.executeQuery();

        tbShowEvent.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ShowEvent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

How to delete one element in table when I click the mouse to that element

[image]
Illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib77V.png

Comment: What you want?? Delete a particular cell or complete Row from table??

Answer (score 0):

- add an event listener on your delete button
- create your stored procedure code for the delete in the event listener.
- after a succesful delete in the DB delete the row in your table in the table Model
- refresh you table. Call fireTableDataChanged() on your tableModel